# validation of a dropdownlist with jquery not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in a table with a blank item in it, I want a error message showed in a label if a button is pressed while that blank item is selected in the dropdrownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListParedesinteriores_ItemChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value='5'>Excellent</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Very good</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Good</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Bad</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Very bad</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

This is my Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#Button1").click(function ()
            {
                var a = $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>");
                if (a.val() === "-1")
                {
                    document.getElementById("Label9").innerHTML = "<b>Please select an option</b>";
                    document.getElementById("Label9").style.color = "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("Label9").innerHTML = "<b>Comfirmed</b>";
                    document.getElementById("Label9").style.color = "green";
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this button is a server side button you have to disable postaback to make it work on client side by using onClientClick="return false" .Secondly  in order to use Button1 as id($("#Button1")) you need to change ClientIDMode to static same goes for the label

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  onClientClick="return false"  ClientIDMode="Static" />
  <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

if you dont want to use static client id  you have to replace

```
$("#Button1") with  $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>")   
document.getElementById("Label9") with document.getElementById("<%= Label9.ClientID %>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button 1 selector "$("#Button1).click" click event does not consider the client ID like your dropdown list does.  That may be causing the issue if jquery finds nothing for button 1 and the click event never gets triggered.

A possible fix is to change the selector to the same as you do in the line where you use jquery to get the dropdown list.

Comment: Tried with `$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function ()` still didn't work

Comment: Your label9 also looks like it needs to have the client id set as well.  Basically everything that runs as runat="server" has to have client id specified on webforms. Hopefully it'll work after that.